# in javascript why is concatenation of two arrays result in type object and not array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeof

I was trying:

```
console.log(typeof [1,2,3].concat([4,5,6]));
```

and result is:

> object

documentation says:

> Arrays and/or values to concatenate into a new array

[taken from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

so why is the result of type `object` and not `array`? how can I have it as `array`?

Comment: Did you test `typeof []` by itself? Has nothing to do with concatenate.

Comment: @epascarello indeed! they are objects i was sure there is `array` type in javascript.

Comment: Nop, there are six types and object. Array is not one of them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures